# Problem with PHP readfile() dumping binary data to the browser

Tags: php, header, readfile

I trying to force a download by the browser here is my code:

```
header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); 
header('Content-type: audio/mp3');
header('Content-Description: File Download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $file_name);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-length: ' . filesize($file_path);
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file_path);
```

This works perfectly on my local machine, but when I upload it to my live server, the binary file is dumped to the browser and those gibberish characters fill up the browser window. What could be the problem? I am on a shared server so I don't know if my apache configuration needs to be changed or something.

I took @sanmi advice and used Firebug to see the response header and here is what I got:

```
Here is what I got sanmai: 
Server  nginx/0.7.67
Date    Tue, 06 Sep 2011 15:02:03 GMT
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Connection  keep-alive
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0   
Pragma  no-cache
Vary    Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Encoding    gzip
```

I can see that the content-type entry has changed to text/html, and that the server is actually a nginx one. So is this a nginx issue or are my header entries wrong?

Thanks,
Tsega

Comment: If you comment ob_clean() and flush() in the server, what's the reponse?

Comment: done that but still same problem.

Answer (score 1):

It turns our one of the files I include had a blank line after the closing php tag. That was the problem, thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: thx a lot. I had an include file that had ended like this:
   ...
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}




}

?> 
    
</div>
-----------------------

now ends like this:

    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
}
?>

and works perfectly. No more binary symbols in the webpage! (a TONS OF THANKS !!!)

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); 
header('Content-type: audio/mp3');
```

You send two `Content-Type`, only one is necessary.

Comment: It doesn't matter. The second will overwrite the first.

Comment: Because he is trying to force the download, the override matter.

Comment: It may not override at all because "This function now prevents more than one header to be sent at once as a protection against header injection attacks." http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: I understand this sentence like it's not more possible to do something like this `header("Header-Y: Hello\nHEader-X: World");`

Comment: removed the one with audio/mp3 and tried still didn't work. It still works locally though.

Answer (score 0):

Use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/network) or [other means](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) to view HTTP headers your server actually sending. It may hide or alter any of them. If so, talk to your hosting's support.

Comment: Add this to your original question, please. Seems to me that you hosting server eats all those headers. Check with the support, we can't help you here.

Comment: I used FireBug and I see that the response header's Content-Type: has changed to text/html; charset=UTF-8. That shouldn't be the case right, I see that the server is a nginx server not an apache one, could that be the issue?

Comment: Thanks @sanmai, I was really suspecting that, I read something on their Knowledge Base, that they use load balancing and have special header info or something like that so I'll check with them. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this might be causing it, but content type audio/mp3 isn't defined(officially): http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/audio/index.html . Try using audio/mpeg?

Comment: I tried you suggestion but the problem still persists. I'm guessing it has to do with the server.